# bash - Capture exit code from remote ssh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm looking at capturing the exit status of a remote ssh command within a shell script 
I have a shell script as follows :

```
function rSSH {
   local x
   echo "Running ssh command"
   x=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $keyPair -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i $keyPair user@$bastionIP 22" user@$IP "$cmd")

   x=$?
   echo "SSH status is : $x"
   if [ $x -eq 0 ];then
      echo "Success"

   else
      echo "Failure"
      exit 1
   fi
}

rSSH
exit 0
```

When I execute the above script as a background job with an invalid $bastionIP( testing failure scenario), it results with an exit code of 0 ( instead of 1) and the only information I see in the logs is the first echo "Running ssh command" and it just exits the script.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or a better way to capture the exit status of the remote ssh command. 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using `set -e`?

Comment: ahh yeah. That's probably causing the issue. @chepner Thanks for pointing that out. Totally missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script appears to be running under `set -e`, which means when the `ssh` connection fails, the script exits immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue. I had to execute a bunch of commands over a remote ssh connection as below and the script will terminate before the 'echo'ing the 'return here='.

```
ssh -v -T -i ${KEY} -p${PORT} -tt ${USER}@${IP} /bin/bash -c "'
echo "Inside Script"
exit 12
'"
echo "return here=$?"
```

Thanks to the response of @chepner in the original post, it was the same issue that I was using 
     `set -e`

Removing it helped to resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Try using another variable for return code.

```
function rSSH {
   local x
   echo "Running ssh command"
   x=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $keyPair -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i $keyPair user@$bastionIP 22" user@$IP "$cmd")

   local ret_code
   ret_code=$?
   echo "SSH status is : $ret_code"
   if [ $ret_code -eq 0 ];then
      echo "Success"

   else
      echo "Failure"
      exit 1
   fi
}

rSSH
exit 0
```

Comment: Why do you the variable name `x` is problematic? You should then change the `local` too.

Comment: You can keep the local.

Comment: You need to update it to also declare `ret_code` as local.